# .ipynb file in Google Drive doesn't open with Colaboratory by default

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-drive-picker

I have two files in my Google Drive with .ipynb extension, but one of them is marked as Unknown File type and has a blue icon. What can I do to change the second one to a Colaboratory file?

[image]

Comment: If you upload file, you will find it as blue icon and if you open that file in colab, it will change. I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get that icon you should save a copy from Colab

1. Upload your file to Drive

   [image]
2. Open a file with Colab

   [image]
3. Save a copy in Drive

   [image]
4. Go to Drive and find folder

   [image]
5. Inside you will find your file with the Colab icon

   [image]

Comment: Thank you. It was the first time that I uploaded a question.