# Unable to open a ipynb file in Colab from Google Drive

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have uploaded files in google drive which are shown there. These are ipynb files, but i am unable to open these files in notebook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive does not recognise .ipynb file as colab notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337334/google-drive-does-not-recognise-ipynb-file-as-colab-notebook)

Comment: i have tried implementing but its giving an error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 6
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 6
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at va.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20220120-060055-RC00_422993309:4968:226)
    at xa (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20220120-060055-RC00_422993309:19:336)
    at va.next_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20220120-060055-RC00_422993309:17:503)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `https://colab.research.google.com/` then use the upload tab to upload the files.

You can also right click and open the files with `Google colaboratory`

Comment: I have tried to upload the notebook but its giving an error. Unexpected token < in JSON at position 6
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 6
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at va.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20220120-060055-RC00_422993309:4968:226)
    at xa (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20220120-060055-RC00_422993309:19:336)

Comment: Are you able to run the notebook locally?

Comment: i am trying to open this file which is present on github too https://github.com/debayanmitra1993-data/Blindness-Detection-Diabetic-Retinopathy-/blob/master/2_process.ipynb

Comment: yes i am able to open the notebook

Comment: It turns out the notebook get corrupt after download, so the problem is not with Google drive and colabs. What you can do  is to create a fresh notebook on colabs and copy the code from github